# Show a sequence of functions is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

I am a bit confused with this question:

[image]

This is the metric D:

[image]

What do they mean by showing convergence? In the answers, it said that showing $(f_{n}(0))_{n}$ is Cauchy suffices but I thought Cauchy did not always imply convergence?

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated :)

Thank you.

Comment: You need to show that the sequence of real values $f_n(x_0)$ converges. It is sufficient to show that the sequence is Cauchy since the reals are complete.

Comment: A Cauchy sequence of real numbers is convergent - and for each $x_0 \in [1/2, 1]$, $(f_n(x_0))_n$ will be a Cauchy sequence of real numbers given the definition of $D$ (you need to prove that). I don't see why the sequence $(f_n(0))_n$ is relevant: is that a typo? (PS: I think your misunderstanding is reflected in the title of your question: this is not about the convergence of a sequence of functions.)

Comment: You need $x_0 \in [\frac12, 1]$ otherwise the sequence in question is not necessarily Cauchy. If a space is complete then Cauchy sequences converge.